# Attach extra metadata to file using fs and nodejs in electronjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, fs

I am using electronjs and react app to sync some files between my server and filesystem. to sync files with filesystem I need to find new files from server and download them to filesystem, so I am using

```
const writer = fs.createWriteStream
```

and inside axios successfull response using to store file like below

```
response.data.pipe(writer);
```

every things fine but I need to sync any changes with filesystem to my server. for example if some old files just moved between some folders , I just need to find that file in my server and change it subfolder and no need to upload it again so I need some uniqe keys to recognize files. each files in my server have uniqe key to recognize.
is it possible to attach some metadata to file whene I am saving it to filesystem like an id?

I know one way is to save files hash and compare files hash but for a large file it could take time.

Comment: I expect you would need the same application on your server listening for changes made to your (local) filesystem (and an initial sync conducted at some point in time). Instead of trying to add metadata to every file for renames, moves and deletes, instead send a delta (a small `.json` data packet containing the specific change to the folder(s) / file(s) only) via an Axios request to your server. That way, your server can perform the rename, move or delete action itself. If you like, it can send a response back to confirm the action was successful.